# Upload image from ImageView with String values using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, image-uploading, android-bitmap

I have a registration form. Along with the user information like First Name, Last Name and Username, I want the user to upload the image.

Currently, I have managed to get the image thumbnail loaded in an ImageView using the camera and displayed in the View. Now I want to upload the image as well.

Below is my code in my `Register.java` that works perfectly fine if only Strings.

```
String requested_method = "register";

RegisterTask registerTask = new RegisterTask(Register.this);
registerTask.execute(requested_method, first_name_entered, last_name_entered, username_entered);
```

Since my `RegisterTask.java` is a large file, therefore I am only pasting the relevant information here.

```
public class RegisterTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;

    public RegisterTask(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String register_url = "http://my_website.com/register.php";
    String requested_method = params[0];
    String first_name = params[1];
    String last_name = params[2];
    String username = params[3];

    if (requested_method.equals("register")) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(submit_order_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("first_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(first_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("last_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(last_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));

            String response_data = "";
            String line = "";

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response_data+= line;
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response_data;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This code is working fine.

Now what I want to do is, add the image that I have loaded in ImageView to this AsyncTask and upload. If I am trying to send Bitmap along with the String, it is giving an error.

What should I do?

Comment: `If I am trying to sent Bitmap along with the String, it is giving an error.`. Show your code and exact error message. What is 'the String'?

Comment: I agree to your point that this statement is nonsense. I should have removed it before posting.

Comment: Error:(287, 21) error: method execute in class AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result> cannot be applied to given types;
required: String[]
found: String,String,String,String,Bitmap
reason: varargs mismatch; Bitmap cannot be converted to String
where Params,Progress,Result are type-variables:
Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
Progress extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask

Comment: Add the bitmap parameter to the constructor. `registerTask = new RegisterTask(Register.this, bitmap);`.

Comment: Not working. If I try to add ´, bitmap´ to the constructor but failed.

Comment: Well what failed? You should of course adapt the parameters of the constructor first.

Comment: I have managed to solve this issue with your support. In one of your comments, which I am unable to find again, you mentioned that what is wrong when you are getting the image in String? The problem was not with the code. Actually I was not saving the data with full-length characters. Can you please put that part as an answer so that I can accept it? Will modify the question accordingly as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a new class, call it `RegistrationDetails`, and have it contain the current strings as well as the `Bitmap`. Just pass an instance of that class as the only argument to the `AsyncTask`.